# grep for file content but return the filename

Tags: linux, grep

I need the GREP syntax for the following task (am in a LINUX OS):

querying ALL files in the CURRENT directory which contain STRING but only listing the FILENAMES which contain a match.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this crosses the line and isn't a programming question. Voting for move to Super User.

Comment: I disagree - for me it is common to embed OS commands in other languages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
grep -rl stringToSearch .
```

or

```
 find . -type f -exec grep -l stringToSearch {} \;
```

For more info on `grep` and other unix command, please refer to manual ( `man` )

In that case `man grep` says that

> -l, --files-with-matches
>                 Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would  normally  have  been  printed.
>   The
>                 scanning will stop on the first match.

Obviously, as a bash command, if your string contains special chars or spaces, you have to (in order) escape them and/or surrounding your string with quotas

Answer (score 1):

"Grep -l" wil give you the list of file names.

```
> echo "hello" > test_file1.list
> echo "hello2.." > test_file2.list
> echo "xyz" > test_file3.list


> grep "hello" test_file*list

test_file1.list:hello
test_file2.list:hello2..


> grep -l "hello" test_file*list
test_file1.list
test_file2.list
```